# How to write another query in IN function when partitioning

Tags: postgresql

I have 2 local docker postgresql-10.7 servers set up. On my hot instance, I have a huge table that I wanted to partition by date (I achieved that). The data from the partitioned table (Let's call it PART_TABLE) is stored on the other server, only PART_TABLE_2019 is stored on HOT instance. And here comes the problem. I don't know how to partition 2 other tables that have foreign keys from PART_TABLE, based on FK. PART_TABLE and TABLE2_PART are both stored on HOT instance.

I was thinking something like this:

```
create table TABLE2_PART_2019 partition of TABLE2_PART for values in (select uuid from PART_TABLE_2019);
```

But the query doesn't work and I don't know if this is a good idea (performance wise and logically).

Let me just mention that I can solve this with either function or script etc. but I would like to do this without scripting.

Comment: I'm not sure you can partition a foreign table since a foreign table itself is just a reference to an external source. You could create one foreign table for each child table on the host database, or have a single table referencing the parent table

Comment: I have already made foreign partitioned table on PART_TABLE.
PART_TABLE_XXXX to PART_TABLE_2018 are all foreign tables on my HOT instance. They are stored on WARM instance but are partitioned from the table PART_TABLE that is on HOT.

Answer (score 0):

From doc at https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-partitioning.html#DDL-PARTITIONING-DECLARATIVE

> "While primary keys are supported on partitioned tables, foreign keys
>   referencing partitioned tables are not supported. (Foreign key
>   references from a partitioned table to some other table are
>   supported.)"

Comment: First, this applies to PostgreSQL v11, not to v10 which OP uses. Second, he is talking about FKs *from* a partitioned table.

Answer (score 0):

With PostgreSQL v10, you can only define foreign keys on the individual partitions. But you could create foreign keys on each partition.

You could upgrade to PostgreSQL v11 which allows foreign keys to be defined on partitioned tables.

Can you explain what a HOT instance is and why it would makes this difficult?